# How to access a single object inside a map using freemarker

Tags: templates, freemarker

Hi i have a object and i'm putting it to map and then passing this map to freemarker. but i'm unable to retrieve it inside free marker.

Here is my code

```
Atm atm =AtmLocatorFeedDao.getAtmDetails(request.getParameter("atmID"), atmList);               
                    map.put("atmdetails", atm );
                    outputData= FreemarkerTemplate.populateTemplateData("atmdetails", branchMap);
```

here is my freemarker template

```
<#assign atmdetails as atm>
<location>
<atmID>${atm.atmId}</atmID>
<atmName>${atm.atmName}</atmName>
</location>
</#assign>
```

Comment: Where do you pass the `map` to FreeMarker, what error message do you get, etc. Also it seem that you put a single `Atm` into the map an then try to list it.

Comment: I think you need `<#list atmdetails as atm>` not `<#assign>`